# Java - specific data structure

Tags: java

I need to perform following operations :

(1) check if elements exists in O(1)

(2) add in O(1)

(3) remove and return in O(1)

I thought about `Set` in java , but it only supports (1) and (2). I know that it is possible to do something like this `set.iterator().next()` and `set.iterator().remove()` but what is the complexity of this solution ?

EDIT

I want something like this :

```
Set<Integer> remaining = new HashSet<>();

// add values

Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

while(!remaining.isEmpty()) {
    int val = remaining.iterator().next();   // !!!
    remaining.iterator().remove();          // !!!
    queue.add(val);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {

         List<Integer> valuesToBeRemoved = getValues();
         // some logic
         for(int value : valuesToBeRemoved) {
              remaining.remove(value);
         }

    }


}
```

and I am wondering if lines marked with // !!! are optimal

Comment: From the documentation of `HashSet`: _"This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)"_ If you want to get an element; you may look into an `HashMap`. Although those datas structures doesn't allow duplicate elements/keys so this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you don't understand me correctly, so I'll try to write it more clearly. I need something like this while(!set.isEmpty() ) {  int val = set.remove()   } It is impossible to do using hashmap, because I must specify element in get method

Comment: Looking at your while loop, just use an iterator get the element and use it's remove method. Or just use a for each loop and clear the set at the end or reinitialize it to a new empty set reference....

Comment: `set.remove()` returns a `boolean`, not an `int`. What do you want the `int` to mean?

Comment: it was an example. I am going to edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you care about the set after the fact, or do you only want the elements in the queue?

Comment: What do you mean by '"after the fact" ? After outer while loop it would be empty. I can't add all elements from set to the queue at the beginning , because I want to avoid a lot of unncecesary calculations

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` has O(1) performance for `add(E e)` and `contains(E e)`. To get any old element from a `HashSet<Integer>` (and remove it) you can write

```
Iterator<Integer> i = set.iterator();
int a = i.next();
i.remove();
```

When you do `i.next()` you might have to search empty hash buckets.

If you use a `LinkedHashSet` rather than a `HashSet`, you get similar performance for `add()` and `contains()`, but `i.next()` is faster because a `LinkedHashSet` keeps a reference to the first element. In general it is much quicker to iterate over a `LinkedHashSet` than a `HashSet` because you just have to follow a chain of references. Note however that a `LinkedHashSet` will be use more memory than a `HashSet`, but if it's speed you're interested in, `LinkedHashSet` is a good answer.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` makes guarantees to insertion order, and is slightly more expensive because of that guarantee.  It should still be amortized O(1), though.